# binding data methods in react.js latest version

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have much experience in Angular. Just learned React. 
Very curious about data binding methods in React.
I think the most effective method is to use ContextAPI.

Answer (score 0):

ContextAPI is not to bind data in component, I think. It's just for sharing data across all levels of the application. Especially can be used to send data to the child components from parent component without passing all paths of DOM tree like when using props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class FormControl extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this); // binding this
  }

  handleChange({ target: { value }) {
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

Or making the `handleChange` func with arrow func is also another way.
From v16.8, we can use React Hooks(like `useState`, `useEffect`, ...) to bind data..
See [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)